# Rest finger while moving cursor Linux Mint 17.1 "Rebecca"

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad

The default touchpad driver "synaptics" doesn't have an option to let you rest one finger on the trackpad and move the cursor with another; it stops the cursor. I'm using a Macbook Air and this is quite a problem.

I saw that other Linux distros have alternatives (e.g "mtracks").

What is a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a bug in the xorg driver:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1026046

I'm desperately searching for a solution to this, too. I'm on Linux Mint 17.3 with 1.8.1 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid (Synaptics Touchpad of a Dell XPS 15 9550).

For the moment, the only solution seems to be

```
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

This makes the finger resting work but disables all scrolling capabilities from your touchpad.